# How height of a text box is calculated in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Though I have already referred box model but could not track
How height of a text box or any HTML element is being calculated in following fiddle

```html
<input type="text" id="test" onclick= "alert('computed height ' + window.getComputedStyle(this).height  + ' and font-size ' +  window.getComputedStyle(this)['font-size'])" name="test" value="Click here to get height" style="
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;    
    line-height: 1;   
"/>
```

I am not able to find  how height of the text box is 15px even if with 0 border,0 margin,0 padding and 13.33px font size.

EDIT- Though firefox works perfect by calculations, but after zooming it cuts some of the content
[image: Text on Firefox]

[image: Text on Chrome]

It Seems chrome applies some formatting to render better than firefox.

Comment: Probably browser dependent...I get differing values based on zoom level.

Comment: Btw, in firefox, computed height is 13.33px too. IE 11, 15.33. :)

Comment: I am wondering if there are specs available for this behaviour

Comment: safari win : 16px, my IE 15.33px ...

Comment: So, Firefox obviously wins again, height=font-size. :)

Comment: Try using a span- https://jsfiddle.net/3xke52up/

Comment: @Paulie_D yea that works perfect across the browsers. tried same on input tag but didn't work :-/

Comment: That's because you're dealing with broswer ui objects...each browser has it's own default styling automatically applied.

Answer (score 2):

Ok Here is the explanation, I learnt by tring.

Refer the specification
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced

which says

> The height of the content area [of inline elements] should be based on the font, but this specification does not specify how. A UA may, e.g., use the em-box or the maximum ascender and descender of the font...

Chrome and fire-fox have different implementation for line-height

***Chrome-***
Chrome will ignore line-height if it is not able to render it perfectly and will increase the space to fit text perfectly.

***FireFox-***
FireFox will also ignore the line-height if it is less than font-size  but it will provide exact space provided as font-size even if is not able to render it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the line-height? try setting it to some px value

if the height is not specified, and border, padding are 0 then it will be the line-height value that is the cause. Each browser have it's own pre defined css. so you have to reset most of them in your css (mostly at the top) so all browsers render the same

edit: I meant, line-height:1 will be different in each browser based on the browsers predefined styles, did you reset the line-height on the body initially. Easy way to find out is giving the line-height a px value and check all browsers

Comment: I have already set it to 1, which means that line height should be same as font size (which is 13.33 here)

Comment: I tried setting both but didn't work, still showing 15px on chrome